# Where are Automator's "Watch Me Do" files saved?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, automator

Where are Automator's "Watch Me Do" files being saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They appear to be part of the workflow, which means they would be saved wherever the workflow file is saved. This varies, depending on what kind of workflow you are creating.

- Services are saved in ~/Library/Services
- Folder Actions are saved in ~/Library/Workflow/Applications/Folder Actions
- Applications and Workflows are saved wherever the user saves them.

Comment: Another question: when I delete "Watch Me Do" from "Automator" does it gets deleted forever?

Comment: You could post that as a question; you'd be more likely to get a response that way.

Comment: @DanielLawson If you don't know where an Application Workflow was saved, is there a way to find out?

Comment: @drevicko I recommend posting that as a question using the "Ask Question" button